# What's the advantage of "one thread per connection" in an HTTP server?

Tags: multithreading, apache, nginx, event-driven, httpserver

If I was programming an HTTP server, why should I consider handling every HTTP connection in its own thread?

I've read plenty of arguments that event-driven HTTP servers are faster and more scalable than thread-driven ones. (For example, see Ars Technica on [Nginx](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/11/a-faster-web-server-ripping-out-apache-for-nginx.ars)). And yet Apache, the world's most popular server, is thread-driven. Why? What are the advantages?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple to code against.

Basically, without language support (such as C# and VB will be getting in their next versions) and really good libraries, writing asynchronous code is hard. Not impossible, and no doubt there will be comments from those who are able to do it standing on their heads, but it's harder than the synchronous version. We're much better at thinking about code which just executes top to bottom than code which has to be reentrant etc.

Depending on your platform, threads can be *quite* cheap these days - so with appropriate pooling, the thread-per-request model works *pretty well* for servers who don't need to handle *that* many requests at a time. It sucks for long-polling, of course, or servers which mostly need to delegate requests to other services which may take "a while" to come back (even if that's only a tenth of a second). The latter class of server *should* be able to handle huge request rates as they're only doing minimal processing to do their work - but if they hog a thread for each request simply to block while waiting for another service to come back, that can be very wasteful, particularly of memory.

Comment: `Basically, without language support (such as C# and VB will be getting in their next versions)`? Huh? .NET has very good support imho (Begin/End methods). Compare with C or C++ in linux. terrible.

Comment: @jgauffin: That's not *language* support. Even with the *library* support, it's still basically painful - especially in terms of error handling. With async/await, however, it's rather more feasible for mere mortals like me to do a reasonable job.

Comment: yes. It's library support. But the library support in linux is far behind .NET. Even the winapi/iocp is greater than linux. I'm just saying that the open source webservers are usually built in linux first or for cross platform and there isn't many alternatives to use then. Thread per request is the easiest (and still effective) approach.